# Can we access the objects outside the method?

Tags: java

I created two Classes `A` and `B`.

I created an object in `B` outside any method like below, but I can't access variables and methods from `A`. Why? I can't understand this

```
Class B {
    int a, b;
    A Obja = new(); // this does not work

    public void method1() {
        A Obja1 = new A(); // from here I am able to access the members from A
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to specify the classname for the `new` keyword.

```
A Obja = new A();
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - Creating objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

---

This would however have resulted in a compilation error, not a runtime error. So if your code actually compiled, then your concrete problem might rather be a scoping or visibility issue. But the code example given as far doesn't indicate any.